# Reading metadata from Qt applications

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, console-application, metadata

I have to use C++ and a sort of process manager instead of `QPluginLoader` in Qt-based application under Windows and Linux. I'd like to receive some metadata from certain Qt-based console apps which serve as plugins. I'd like not to run app before I read metadata (for example, version info and so on). What should I use for that purpose? I can modify plugin-apps.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you have 2 solutions.

You can use "Version Information", which is basically the information you have when you do a "Right-Click -> Properties -> Details". It will get you different fields like the file description, the file version, company name...
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/version-information

Another solution is to use the resource system: you embed a file into the exe and retrieve it later on. This system is used to embed icons for instance.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea

For Linux, it is more complicated as it seems that there is no mechanism to do that out-of-the-box. But, you can find several ways to inject data into an elf file on the Internet. Maybe you can make use of this answer: [Packing a file into an ELF executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900936/packing-a-file-into-an-elf-executable)